# How to bind cronExpression value to a formControl?

Tags: angular

I use this cron library https://github.com/claudiuconstantin/cron-editor

```
<cron-editor [(cron)]="cronExpression" [disabled]="isCronDisabled" [(options)]="cronOptions"></cron-editor>
<hr /> 
<p>The resulting Cron expression: <strong>{{cronExpression}}</strong></p>
```

I need to bind the resulting expression to my form control

`testControl: new FormControl('')`

I tried this

```
testControl: new FormControl(this.cronExpression)
```

But it's null

Comment: How are you getting the value of `cronExpression` in your code? Are you assigning that yourself?

Comment: it is part of that library. it is created automatically

Comment: also tried this `<input formControlName = "testControl" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{cronExpression}}">`

Comment: assigning to value attribute will definitely not work! (assuming you are seeing the value when you set to `value`. Don't you?) So wherever you are creating the formControl, please log the `cronExpression` value just before that and tell what you see.

Comment: when i create the formControl, the value for cronExpression is the default `public cronExpression = '4 3 2 12 1/1 ? *';`

Comment: Yes. I see the value {{cronExpression}}. I need to assign or bind this value to my formControl

Comment: I see, I had added that comment seeing you added `null` as log. Now if it has value then it doesn't make sense for the control to not have the default value. Please show, if your control is in a FormGroup or Independent and how are you using it in your template.

Comment: the control has the default value. but then i change cron, the cronExpression changes but testControl doesnt catch up and still has the default value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184937/discussion-between-xyz-and-john).